# Can I clone a cinema website's seat selector, using contrib modules?

Tags: 7

I'd like to clone the functionality you get on many cinema websites, where it shows you the seating plan for the cinema and lets you pick a seat. Seats that have already been booked are in one colour, available seats are in another colour, the seats you currently have selected are in a third colour.

How close can I get to this functionality only using contrib modules?

Comment: Yes, probably you can, but we don't do "feature from scratch" here. And without a link it is not clear what exactly you want to copy. With link, it would be off-topic, because cloning linked sites is defined off-topic in help center.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. I'm asking "can Drupal do this", seems like a sensible question for a Drupal Q and A site?!

Comment: This site is more for things like "I have cinema seat selection function on my website and I have done such and such but there is this part that doesn't work properly. How can I fix it?" where as this is more along the lines of "How can I make a cinema seat selection website?", which is too broad, there are too many possible different answers and it is kind of asking others to design your solution for you, which is off topic here. If you just want to know "Can Drupal do this?" then yes, it can, but it is complex feature design that has many elements and there are many potential solutions.

Comment: Which solution is the best for you no one on here would know because they don't know all the factors involved in your project.

Comment: I see the logic behind your argument, but someone has been able to provide a useful answer to my question (see below). Are there other forums or Q and A sites that would be better suited to this sort of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Reservation](https://www.drupal.org/project/reservation) module.

Reservation module is for reserving individual seats at a theater or restaurant

> This module allows site users to reserve a unit. A unit could be anything, but the most common are rooms or pieces of equipment. Site builders create the units that can be reserved, adding any additional fields. Validation of reservations is done using Rules, which can be customized by the site builder.

There are a number of other reservation type modules available, including *Simple Reservation*, *Reservations*, and *Checkfront*. But this module seems that it meets your requirement.